# Fix a absolutePanel on the top within a dashboardBody

Tags: r, shiny

I want to fix a absolutePanel on the top of other three tabPanel within a dashboardBody. But now the maps overlap the box, how should I do?

Example code:

```
    dashbody=dashboardBody(
      tags$style(type="text/css","#mapplot{height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;"),
      absolutePanel(top=60,right=10,width=300,draggable=TRUE,box(title="box")) ,
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("map",leaflet:::leafletOutput("mapplot"),mapview:::plainViewOutput("test"),value=1),
                  tabPanel("plot",value=2),
                  tabPanel("summary",value=3),
                  tabPanel("table",value=4)) 
)
```

---

**EDIT:**
I have soved it by reorder the absolutePanel and tabsetPanel.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have soved it by reorder the absolutePanel and tabsetPanel.